# Issues getting preloader animation to show up when render.com server is spinning up (free tier web service)

Tags: javascript, jquery, preloader, render.com

I am using render.com to deploy my dynamic websites and have opted to use their free tier. Render will spin down the free web service after 15 minutes of inactivity and spin the service back up whenever it next receives a request to process. However, spinning up a service from idle takes quite a bit of time, causing a noticeable delay for incoming requests until the service is back up and running. The result is that the browser page load will hang momentarily.

To make the experience more user friendly I decided to create a preloader animation that shows up while the server is spinning up from idle (using fetch). However, my current code only works *after* the server has been spun up. I am clearly doing something wrong but am completely stumped.

Here is my current code that checks if the service is up and handles the preload animation using jQuery.

```
// Function to check if the service is up using async/await
async function isServiceUp() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("https://cookyourkitchen.onrender.com"); 
      console.log(response);

    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error checking service status:', error);
      return false; // Service is down or unreachable
    }
  }

$(document).ready( () => {
    if(isServiceUp){
        $("#loader").fadeOut(1000);
        $("#content").fadeIn(1000);
    } else {
        $("#loader").show();
    }
    
});
```

Here is the html (ejs) that is relevant to my problem.

```
<body>
    <div id="loader" class="loader"></div>

    <div id="content" class="container">
        <div class="px-4 py-5 my-4 text-center">
            <h1 class="display-5 fw-bold text-body-emphasis">Cook Your Kitchen</h1>
            <div class="col-lg-6 mx-auto">
                <p class="lead mb-4">Have some random ingrediants in your kitchen? <br>
                    Those veggies about to go bad?? <br>
                    Enter the ingrediants you want to use and get recipe suggestions!
                </p>
                <form action="/search" method="post">
                    <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-sm-flex justify-content-sm-center">
                        <input type="text" id="search" name="ingrediants" class="form-control"
                            placeholder="Chicken, beans, tomato,..." aria-label="Recipient's username"
                            aria-describedby="button-addon2">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" value="Submit" id="button-addon2">Get a recipe</button>
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js" integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4=" 
       crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <script src="preloadwebpage.js"></script>
       <script src="loadrecipes.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what's going on here.

First, in your snippet, you're not calling the `isServiceUp` function:
`if (isServiceUp)` will always be true because your asking if a function pointer is true (function pointers are truthy). I think you meant to call it instead: `if (isServiceUp())`.

Next, `isServiceUp` is async, and when you call it, it returns a Promise, which is also truthy. If you want to know the outcome of the operation, you need to `await` it, which means you need `.ready` to be async (which jquery supports):

```js
$(document).ready( async () => { 
   var isUp = await isServiceUp();
   if (isUp){
      $("#loader").fadeOut(1000);
      $("#content").fadeIn(1000);
   } else {
      $("#loader").show();
   }
});
```

That worked for me. ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zerbwmxq/5/))

It's a good idea adding a spinner to wait for the render instance to spin back up. There are options to keep your free tier instance from going down in the first place if rather not jump through hoops. [I wrote one that's free](https://keepalive.dashdashhard.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 100% meant to call `isServiceUp()` as a function in the if statement (talk about a rookie mistake, smh!). I implemented your solution locally and this resulted in the browser page hanging indefinitely. I realized that my `response` const in `isServiceUp()` was actually returning undefined so I added an if statement that returns true or false based on the status of `response.ok`. This fixed the indefinite hanging of the browser but still does not really address my problem in that preloader animation shows up after the server has been spun up.

Comment: Here's a fiddle of what I got working: https://jsfiddle.net/zerbwmxq/5/ 
I forgot to mention before that I added a return true to the try block that fetches from the server if it comes back.
In my take, I start with the spinner always being displayed and letting fadeOut set display:none, and with the other content being display:none to start and fadeIn make it appear.
Sounds like either your isServiceUp is returning the wrong thing, or the style you've applied to the spinner isn't compatible with fadeOut.